# "does not name a type error" while accessing a structure variable in class definition although an instance of structure is created in the class

Tags: c++

I am trying to access the structure variable `a` of the structure `n1` from the code below. I'm getting the following error "does not name a type error".

In the code `pout` is the variable of type `n1`. When I try to access the structure member `a`. When I create object of class `ABC` and tried accessing the structure member `a`. The error is resolved. Could anyone tell me  why `pout.a = 5` resulted in an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct {
    int a;
}n1;

class ABC {
  public:
    int c = 8;   **// no error**
    n1 pout; // **created  n1 structure instance**
    pout.a = 5;  // **getting error here as does not name a type error**
};
```

Comment: Because `pout.a = 5` is not the correct syntax to initialize a struct member, you have to initialize the whole struct in one go. Use : `n1 pout{5};`. Side note `typedef struct` is legacy "C" syntax, use `struct n1 { int a };`. You can initialize a in n1 too

Answer (score 0):

Your fixed code would look like this :

```
// using namespace std; // dont use this!

struct n1
{
    int a;
};

struct n2
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

class ABC
{
public:
    int c = 8;   
    n1 pout{ 5 }; 
    n2 pout2{ 3,4 }; // for a struct with more values
};

int main()
{
    ABC abc;
    return abc.pout.a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write code outside of functions. You can only have declarations outside functions and a statement like `pout.a = 5;` is not a declaration. If you want to initialize `pout` you can use brace initialization:

```cpp
class ABC {
public:
    int c = 8;
    n1 pout{5};     // <- like this
};
```

You also do not need to `typedef` your classes in C++. They are automatically `typedef`ined, so just do:

```cpp
struct n1 {
    int a;
};
```

If `5` is a default value for `a` that you'd like in all instances of `n1`:

```cpp
struct n1 {
    int a = 5;  // <-
};

class ABC {
public:
    int c = 8;
    n1 pout; // pout.a will be 5
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Why can't we access a structure member seperately and initialize them using a " dot" operator inside the class.

Comment: @gadepalliabhilash You're welcome! I updated the answer to clarify.